# All I get is the grub screen after interrupting

Tags: grub2, system-installation, kubuntu

I am giving my mom kubuntu on her laptop. While installing I interrupted the process.I tried to reboot the laptop and when rebooting all I get  id the grub screen, I can't do anything.

[image: screen]

Comment: "While installing I interrupted the process." I suggest that you reinstall. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks but I can’t, I get the screen that I showed in the question. I don’t have any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have interrupted it. Hold the Esc key after rebooting/turning on the computer. You should be able to select what you would want to boot from, if not, try the Fn keys or Del(ete). Select the USB drive to boot. I would reply to your comment "Thanks, but the computer is already set to boot from the usb first.", but don't have enough reputation. So, because you interrupted the process, it means that Ubuntu may have set itself to boot by default instead of the USB, so you have to make sure you are booting from the USB.

If it doesn't work, re-flash the ISO to the USB and try the installation again.

Comment: Thank you, I get it to work.

Comment: @Todd If an answer is helpful, please accept it with the check mark instead of commenting. You are new here, so you will also get 15 reputation and access to upvoting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to boot from the install CD or USB. In the BIOS update the boot drive to the CD or USB. It should be under Boot menu. Hold the escape key to get to the BIOS when booting. Your PC might use a different button to take you to the BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, but the computer is already set to boot from the usb first.